# importing class of module from different path in python: "NameError: name 'enpy' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, pip

I have a `exmple.py` script that tries to build the object from the module that resides in `__main__.py` from a different directory as shown here:

```
├─ /enpy
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  └─ __main__.py
│
└─/tests
   ├─ /filetest
   │  └─ train.json
   │
   └─ example.py
```

The **main.py** has one class called Enpy and it start like this and has a lot of different functions:

**MAIN.PY**

```
# Dependancies
import json
import csv

class Enpy:
    # Global Variables
    dataset = None

    # initialize class
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.readDataset(file)
    
    # Functions
    def readDataset(self, file):
        with open(file) as f:
            self.dataset = json.load(f)
```

Then I am not sure import the library enpy and use the class in main.py. So for now in the **example.py** I have

**EXAMPLE.PY**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../enpy')

from enpy import *

# TESTING 

# 1. Creating Enpy Object
enpyObj = enpy.Enpy('./filetest/train.json')
```

I am getting the error when I try to run my **example.py** where I import my local library in the folder **./enpy**

> enpyObj = enpy.Enpy('./filetest/train.json')

> NameError: name 'enpy' is not defined

I know there are a lot of questions about this issue, but it is not very clear about importing classes. Thanks!

Comment: Use `importlib.resources` to read data files (in your case the Json file). There is no need for `sys.path` modifications. Call your code from the directory containg your top level package (`enpy`): `python tests/example.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `enpy` using an absolute path. So you can use [`SourceFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader) to import from a absolute path:

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

enpy = SourceFileLoader("module.name", "/path/to/enpy/__init__.py").load_module()
enpyObj = enpy.Enpy('./filetest/train.json')
```

Comment: That did not work, also because it is missing `load_module(fullname="enpy")`. I have found that running `example.py` in the main directory, rename `__main__.py` to for example `Enpy.py` and then change to `from enpy import Enpy` and `enpyObj = Enpy.Enpy('./tests/filetest/train.json')` as well as all my other paths: works.